# How do I move a window when two-finger scroll is enabled?

Tags: 11.10, window-manager, macbook, trackpad, mouse-scroll

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my MacBook Pro, and I have enabled two-finger scroll.

Now I'm unable to move a window with the trackpad, which is usually done by click-and-holding the window title (with one finger) and dragging (with another finger).

How do I move a window without disabling the two-finger scroll?

Answer (score 4):

Now I don't use a multi-touch pad, but the way I do it is double-tap (one finger twice) on the title bar, but on the last tap stay down and drag it.

You might have to make sure "Enable mouse clicks with touchpad" is enabled in the touchpad Mouse Settings.

Comment: Thanks, you made me figure out what I could do: I can move the window if I just click-and-hold once on the title bar, and use that same finger to move the window. I have disabled tap-to-click, since the the whole MacBook trackpads works as a regular mouse button. I'd still want to move windows the way I do it in MacOSX, though...

Comment: According to [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch#uTouch_Overview) you should be able to use the three-finger click-drag to move a window. Thought you may have to do it on the title bar.

Comment: Yeah, I've discovered that.  Very annoying, since I want three-finger swipes to do something else: http://askubuntu.com/questions/105359  :-P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MacBook peculiarity, but as far as I know you can always press `Alt` key and drag the window from any point contained in it (not just title bar).

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Ubuntu wiki on Multitouch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch).  In 11.10 and 12.04, a three-finger swipe on a touchpad moves the window and it seems *impossible* to disable as neu242 comments.

In 12.04 a three-finger tap brings up red circles that (for me) start moving the window around at random. I think this is the "Unity MultiTouch Grab Handles".  You can turn this off if you install CompizConfig Settings Manager.