# How do I enable OSX-like three-finger swipes in 11.10 and 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, unity, macbook, trackpad

In MacOSX the default settings is to move back/forward a page in Firefox when I do a three-finger swipe left/right.

In Unity, three-finger-swipes invokes window movement.

How can I configure trackpad swipes?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into Touchegg? it provides multitouch gesture options.

Check [this post](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-in-macbook-pro.html) for more info.

Comment: I'm looking at it now, and I'm unable to disable the default three-finger swipe action (move window).

Comment: @Arian, welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While this link may answer the question, [it would be preferrable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Thank you.